# Dell Latitude E5570 USB mouse does not work Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, mouse, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude E5570 with Windows 7 that will not recognize a USB mouse.

I've tried two different mice that I've verified as working on other machines.  The touchpad works and the USB mouse also works in BIOS, but I really need to use a USB mouse in Windows.

Here is what I've tried:

- Fiddled with the relevant BIOS settings involving the mouse and USB support.  I even tried enabling "USB power while sleeping" and that didn't make a difference.  I restored it back to factory default after my changes and still nothing.
- After booting to Windows, I check device manager and in each instance I have an "Unknown device"  I've tried uninstalling the device, rebooting, then plugging the mouse in.  I've tried searching for device drivers which also fails

I've read elsewhere to try power cycling by disconnecting power and removing the battery BUT, the way this laptop is built I cannot do that without taking it apart and I do not have the proper tools to do it here.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Have you tested to see if the USB port is faulty or not? If so, please [go here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/product/latitude-e5570-laptop/drivers) to get the latest drivers - look for chipset and USB 3.0 drivers.

Comment: The USB mouse works in the BIOS screen, but not when Windows boots.  It doesn't matter which USB port I use on the laptop.  Updating drivers couldn't hurt at this point though.

Comment: @adampski Updating the BIOS solved the problem!  Thank you so much!  I'll gladly credit you if you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get the latest drivers and firmware available [from here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/product/latitude-e5570-laptop/drivers).